# vim tab header not visible? I am not able to see tab header in vim when opened multiple files using vim -p *.

Tags: vim

I am not able to see tab header in vim. I have opened multiple files using vim -p *.
I can switch between tabs but not tab header is displayed. I am connecting to a remote server using putty and I am using screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'showtabline'` option is what dictates the presence or absence of the tabline. See `:help 'showtabline'`.

Also, may I suggest you to stop using Vim's tabs as proxies for buffers? Tabs are "viewports" or "workspaces": they are not designed at all to work like the tabs you are used to in other programs.